# Encrypting/Decrypting information at run-time

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography

I'm pretty stuck on this. I have a username and password as strings within my application that are used for Javamail; however I of course don't want to leave these as plain text and run the risk of having my application decompiled and combed through.

A few had suggested that I look into asymmetric encryption (Using BouncyCastle possibly ); however I'm still unaware how that would entirely help.

I don't have much, if any, experience in cryptography so bear with me here: If I'm using a public/private key pair and I want my application to be able to read the string - then the decrypting key would be the "public key" but that doesn't really make sense to me because it completely defeats the purpose of the encryption. If I have the encrypting key as the "public key" then all my application could do is encrypt the string - not decrypt it.

So my questions here are:

- 1) Is my reasoning flawed on this?
- 2) How do I solve this dilemma?

Comment: Interesting. Personally I don't see a way to keep both 'secret' and 'encrypted' part within one app, since it's violation of main encryption principle as I understand it. But lets wait for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store them in the app, best you could do is obfuscate them. Encryption is one way of doing this, but it will stop only the casual 'hacker'. If you have encrypted strings as resources (or class fields), in order to decrypt them, you will need the key to be in the app. If someone would decompile your app, it would be fairly easy to find the key too. You could make this a bit harder by generating the key dynamically, from different places in your code, but, as mentioned above, the attacker could just find the place where the secrets are used and dump the already decrytped stings. There is really no easy way out of this.

You could build a simple Web service that requires authentication using a Google account (which pretty much every Android user has on their device), and have it send the mails on behalf of the user (if that fits your requirements). That way, you would at least know who is sending the mails and block them if they try to use it for spam, go over quota, etc. Of course, they could get a new Google account fairly easily, but if your service is purposefully targeted you will have bigger problems that that. Another downside is that your app will require permissions to access the accounts on the device, which some users might see as a privacy concern.

Comment: Thanks for the input; That's pretty much what I was assuming. The way I try to look at it is "what if I open source the code" which I will probably do anyhow to add to my portfolio. I've decided to just write a short PHP script and use the mail() function to do what I wanted; just using the HttpClient from Android to pass the info.

Answer (score 1):

Rephrasing your question, you want your application to have access to sensitive information which your user should not be able to access. The short answer: find another project to work on because this one is not going to secure your secret. Your best alternative is to provide a proxy service which is on a machine you are certain is secure; let it hold your secrets and let your application contact the proxy for everything it needs to do.

You expressed a primary concern of decomplication to discover your secret. Lets say encryption was viable here (it's not). If I put on my black hat, I would decompile, find the API call which receives the decrypted data in its parameters, and either add additional code to output this data, or just set a breakpoint here.

Comment: Thanks; that pretty much confirmed my original thoughts - I wanted to make sure since I haven't played with it that much that my reasoning wasn't juts flawed.